Get the statistics_stream on SQL server using SSMS
I have generated statistics for a few columns of a table using the following SQL command:
CREATE STATISTICS [STAT_NAME] on [TABLE_NAME] (COLUMN_NAME) WITH FULLSCAN

The generated statistics are showing in the statistics folder in the table.
Now I want to read the STATS_STREAM of my generated statistics. So that I can reuse this stat as follows:
CREATE STATISTICS [STAT_NAME] on [TABLE_NAME] (COLUMN_NAME) WITH STATS_STREAM = 0x<Hexadecimal number>

How can I do that? Are there any commands or SSMS UI option that could do that?


Right click the database -> Generate Scripts
Select the desired table(s)
In the "Advanced" scripting options choose "Script statistics and histograms" in the dropdown next to "Script Statistics"


